# "This is no place for bot" when I type in address without "www"

Tags: wordpress, url, browser, dns, bots

I seem to be the first person in the history of the internet to get this message and I get it in all web browsers... google searching it comes up blank. When I type in "missoulacurrent.com" which is a wordpress site I just built for a client, I get the message "This is no place for bot" in a grey box as seen in the screenshot

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPGFY.png)

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? I have the proper A records in my DNS.

tip to reproduce, if the browser automatically adds the w's, delete them and press enter again. I have to do this in chrome to reproduce the issue. but the problem happens in firefox every time.

Comment: the site comes up fine for me

Answer (score 0):

This is coming from your server, and your wp installation. Your correct domain is most likely "www.misoulacurrent.com"

While I've never seen that behavior in wordpress, it definitely looks like a wordpress "feature"

I would guess it is to discourage crawlers and such. Check your htaccess file and wp settings.

If you're running on apache and have access to your web directory, try running:

```
find . | xargs grep "place for bot" 2> /dev/null
```

And identify how that script is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

you've probably solved this, but just for others that may have this issue, it has just happened to me, but i found that the slug of the homepage was set to 'home' rather than'/' - i changed this and it now shows normally.